# what happens with my array? items disappear

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

what happens with my result array here? i expected the size of the result array to be equal to the input array, but its missing 3 entries.. where did they go? they didn't go to $ret , as they were supposed to..

code:

```
<?php
init();
$list_xy = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => '308',
        'x' => '37',
        'y' => '63'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => '963',
        'x' => '38',
        'y' => '134'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => '385',
        'x' => '39',
        'y' => '132'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'id' => '1231',
        'x' => '50',
        'y' => '199'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'id' => '788',
        'x' => '51',
        'y' => '59'
    ),
    5 => array(
        'id' => '1151',
        'x' => '53',
        'y' => '61'
    ),
    6 => array(
        'id' => '671',
        'x' => '55',
        'y' => '60'
    ),
    7 => array(
        'id' => '1487',
        'x' => '55',
        'y' => '55'
    )
);
$sorted_list_xy = sort_by_xy_distance($list_xy);
$sorted_list_xy_size = count($sorted_list_xy, COUNT_NORMAL);
$list_xy_size = count($list_xy, COUNT_NORMAL);
var_dump($sorted_list_xy_size == $list_xy_size ? "looks right" : "something is wrong", $sorted_list_xy_size, $list_xy_size);
die("died");


function sort_by_xy_distance($input_list)
{
    $ret = array();
    $a = $input_list[0];
    array_push($ret, $input_list[0]);
    $input_list[0] = null;
    $i = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($input_list); ++$i) {
        if ($input_list[$i] == null) {
            echo 'already added to list..';
            continue;
        }
        $ii = 1;
        $tmpdistance = 0;
        $nearest = array(
            'index' => -1,
            'distance' => PHP_INT_MAX
        );
        for ($ii = 1; $ii < count($input_list); ++$ii) {
            if ($input_list[$ii] == null || $ii == $i) {
                //echo 'already added to list..';
                continue;
            }
            $tmpdistance = abs($input_list[$ii]['x'] - $a['x']) + abs($input_list[$ii]['y'] - $a['y']);
            if ($tmpdistance < $nearest['distance']) {
                $nearest['index'] = $ii;
                $nearest['distance'] = $tmpdistance;
            }
        }
        assert($nearest['index'] != -1);
        array_push($ret, $input_list[$nearest['index']]);
        $a = $input_list[$nearest['index']];
        $input_list[$nearest['index']] = null;
    }
    return $ret;
}





function init()
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
}
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
```

output:

> already added to list..already added to list..already added to
>   list..string(18) "something is wrong" int(5) int(8) died

expected output: (something similar to)

> already added to list..already added to list..already added to
>   list..string(11) "looks right" int(8) int(8) died

what i expected the list to turn in to:
a list where the difference to the next's [x][y] is as little as possible, which would be:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "308"
    ["x"]=>
    string(2) "37"
    ["y"]=>
    string(2) "63"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "788"
    ["x"]=>
    string(2) "51"
    ["y"]=>
    string(2) "59"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1151"
    ["x"]=>
    string(2) "53"
    ["y"]=>
    string(2) "61"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "671"
    ["x"]=>
    string(2) "55"
    ["y"]=>
    string(2) "60"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1487"
    ["x"]=>
    string(2) "55"
    ["y"]=>
    string(2) "55"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "385"
    ["x"]=>
    string(2) "39"
    ["y"]=>
    string(3) "132"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "963"
    ["x"]=>
    string(2) "38"
    ["y"]=>
    string(3) "134"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1231"
    ["x"]=>
    string(2) "50"
    ["y"]=>
    string(3) "199"
  }
}
```

I suck at making graphical illustrations, but ill give it a go.
This is my map:
[map http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img633/3521/E0HGRe.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img633/3521/E0HGRe.png)

i need to visit all the black dots. 
This is my current path:
[image]

this path is not very optimal..
here is the path i want: 
[image]

and that's what the sort function is trying to find, the shortest path to visit all the black dots.

Comment: I read program code a lot. However, it can be made easier if there are 'spaces' to break up long strings into 'tokens'. You provide a lot of code. May i suggest you format it according to some easy to read standard? i.e. [The intent of this guide is to reduce cognitive friction when scanning code from different authors. It does so by enumerating a shared set of rules and expectations about how to format PHP code](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). Spaces between things is 'good'. People read and write  code - make it easy for them to understand your code?

Comment: huh, actually stackoverflow don't allow me to end code with a blank newline :p .. anyway, ran it through phpformatter.com with PEAR-style, does it look better now? :o

Comment: to say it in an other way. i have a X/Y flat map. i have many locations on this map i wish to visit. i need to find the shortest (flying) route, to visit all these points on the map. that's what the sort function is (supposed to be) doing. 
However, a breakthrough, i think its wrong to check for ($input_list[$i] == null)  , as i shouldn't care about that, i should just make sure $a is never null, and i make sure of that in if ($input_list[$ii] == null || $ii == $i) ..

Comment: @hanshenrik: To be honest, I do not understand in detail what you're trying  … just a few hints: (a) to sort arrays with a custom callback, use `usort()`. (b) to iterate over arrays, use `foreach` instead of `for`. (c) always compare with `===` (identity) instead of `==` (equality).

Comment: now you can look at my ugly illustrations that try to explain what the code is trying to do :p

Comment: It helps. thanks for the update to your question. You specify what is required.

Comment: i think i solved it. here is fully copy & paste runnable testcode with real data:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ST3saHj2 (too big to post on stackoverflow with its 30000 character/post limit)

looking at both the numbers posted by php, and looking at the result in game, it looks like everything is sorted correctly. the shortest path is found. all i did to fix the algorithm, was to remove the first NULL check :)

Comment: @hanshenrik, Shouldn't your distance be: `hypot(($input_list[$ii]['y'] - $input_list[$ii]['x']), ($a['y'] - $a['x']));`

Comment: $tmpdistance=hypot(($input_list[$ii]['y'] - $input_list[$ii]['x']), ($a['y'] - $a['x']));

? no, but that code had a funny effect: 
http://imageshack.com/a/img912/3276/FUXmeH.jpg

Comment: compare to this: http://imageshack.com/a/img538/1734/rauT6r.png (same number of items, same locations, just better sorted. each change in direction indicate a item has been reached. the walking distance create white dots. the goal is to create as few white dots as possible, while still entering all the 450 specific spots on the map.)

Comment: Ahhh im an idiot... x -x and y-y ... duh

Comment: if you got any suggestions that might produce a better result, I'm all ears

Comment: Nope you have it right... i just go my coords and what not confused i think. Im sure there is probably a more elegant way to code it up, but what you have seems to work.

Comment: slightly interesting, turns out this is called the "Traveling Salesman Problem" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distance calculation you should use Pythagoras' theorem (or just `hypot`, like  @prodigitalson mentioned). For geo coordinates you could use this: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Let's fix your code. Every step of your first loop should take one value from input value and place it into result. But it has continue inside, therefor some steps of first loop do not do their job. Try to remove first continue.

```
$list_xy = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => '308',
        'x' => '37',
        'y' => '63'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => '963',
        'x' => '38',
        'y' => '134'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => '385',
        'x' => '39',
        'y' => '132'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'id' => '1231',
        'x' => '50',
        'y' => '199'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'id' => '788',
        'x' => '51',
        'y' => '59'
    ),
    5 => array(
        'id' => '1151',
        'x' => '53',
        'y' => '61'
    ),
    6 => array(
        'id' => '671',
        'x' => '55',
        'y' => '60'
    ),
    7 => array(
        'id' => '1487',
        'x' => '55',
        'y' => '55'
    )
);
$sorted_list_xy = sort_by_xy_distance($list_xy);
$sorted_list_xy_size = count($sorted_list_xy, COUNT_NORMAL);
$list_xy_size = count($list_xy, COUNT_NORMAL);
var_dump($sorted_list_xy_size == $list_xy_size ? "looks right" : "something is wrong", $sorted_list_xy_size, $list_xy_size);
die("died");

function sort_by_xy_distance($input_list)
{
    $ret = array();
    $a = $input_list[0];
    array_push($ret, $input_list[0]);
    $input_list[0] = null;
    $i = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($input_list); ++$i) {
//                                                         up here
//        if ($input_list[$i] == null) {
//            echo 'already added to list..';
//            continue;
//        }
        $ii = 1;
        $tmpdistance = 0;
        $nearest = array(
            'index' => -1,
            'distance' => PHP_INT_MAX
        );
        for ($ii = 1; $ii < count($input_list); ++$ii) {
            if ($input_list[$ii] == null || $ii == $i) {
                //echo 'already added to list..';
                continue;
            }
            $tmpdistance = abs($input_list[$ii]['x'] - $a['x']) + abs($input_list[$ii]['y'] - $a['y']);
            if ($tmpdistance < $nearest['distance']) {
                $nearest['index'] = $ii;
                $nearest['distance'] = $tmpdistance;
            }
        }
        assert($nearest['index'] != -1);
        array_push($ret, $input_list[$nearest['index']]);
        $a = $input_list[$nearest['index']];
        $input_list[$nearest['index']] = null;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: It's not useless. it's faster.
it's consistent with c/c++, and it uses fewer opcodes than the post-increment, and the `old` value is not returned, only the new value, so we don't need 2 values (old value AND new value, as the post-increment does) 
But don't take my word for it, benchmark it yourself: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kvDpyNY3
my output: the fastest was pre-increment. (...) the difference was: 0.73859477043152 seconds.

-- and running it 4-5 times, it's consistent, pre-increment is about 0.7 seconds faster to count to 100 million, on my server.

Comment: So, you should change your array_push.

Comment: yep it does. you should remove the notice about ++$i , it's wrong (benchmark it if you don't believe me). also you could clarify on array_push, its slower when adding 1 item, but faster when adding 2 or more items (and i am just adding 1 item)